# How can I see the total number of edges and/or Genus in an imported OBJ file using Meshlab?

Tags: mesh, euler-angles, wavefront, meshlab, eulers-number

Is there any way to see the `total number of edges` and/or the `genus` used in the euler number formula using MeshLab?

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [80.lv](https://80.lv/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/david_edit3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: please give more detail or sample codes.

Comment: There is no code. Meshlab is an application. http://www.meshlab.net/
I asked this question by clicking on their ask a question button.

Comment: screenshots? then

Comment: In this screenshot, you can see the number of vertices and faces on the bottom but not the number of edges.
https://80.lv/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/david_edit3.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Filters >> Quality Measures and Computations >> Compute Topological Measures`

Then, hit CTRL+L to open the layer dialog, which shows in the filter output vertices, edges, facets, boundary edges, number of connected components, number of holes, genus, and whether the mesh is manifold or not.

Comment: Thank you, this is it. This is the answer.